# String Replace "&" in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string, replace

How do I replace a "&" in a string in vb.net. I have tried:

```
str2 As String = Replace(str, "&"c, "&amp;")
str2 As String = Replace(str, "&", "&amp;")
str2 As String = Replace(str, chr(38), "&amp;")
```

For some reason it is not working here is the code. I am using a parameter in the URL and using request to store the parameter. It is definitly storing correctly, because when I debug i see that strOne is gettign the correct valeu.

```
        Dim strOne As String = Request("One")
```

IN DEBUG HERE WATCHING strOne = "ABC D＆E"

```
        If Not strOne Is Nothing Then
            strOne = strOne.Replace("&", "&amp;")
        Else
            strOne = String.Empty
        End If
```

Then it goes to the line to replace, and it doesnt. Why???
Ok I figured it out....

The "＆" is not the same as the "&", so I copied and pasted it from the watch and it fixed it. How come they are different? Different encoding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
Dim str2 As String = str.Replace("&", "&amp;")
```

But if it is because of a url, you should take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709694/vb-replace-problem-with-html-ascii-codes)

> you might look at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode instead.

Comment: If Not strOne Is Nothing Then
                stryOne = strIndustryOne.Replace("&", "&amp;")
            Else
                strOne = String.Empty
            End If

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str2 As String = str.Replace("&", "&amp;")
```

Comment: Sorry, I just finished arguing with a person who kept talking about how VB.NET is stupid and difficult to use, I'll take it out.

Comment: I see your code above, what exactly about it is not working? If you mean to replace &amp; with &, it's: `Dim str2 As String = str.Replace("&amp;", "&")`